# Download blob from azure storage using c++

Tags: c++, libcurl, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download file from azure blob storage using c++ and lib curl. It works fine when azure storage container is publicly opened and storage is private I need to provide authentication string header to download the file. While googling I found using REST services I can do this. I found some qt/c++ code as well but I don't want to use qt here. Can anyone help me out to provide some sample code for this?

Comment: I take it you've reviewed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179440.aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx

Comment: Yeah true but here problem is we have to decode storage key. That i am not very much sure how to do.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late to put this answer down now, but there is a C++ version of Azure Storage Client Library available at github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-cpp, and NuGet package available at: http://www.nuget.org/packages/wastorage/0.5.0-preview.